# Visual Studio, Windows 8 HTML5 Javascript Questions

Tags: javascript, html, windows-runtime

Was not sure what to title this post, I've been having a go at trying to make a little Windows 8 app, I don't have much knowledge and sorry in advance if this is hard to understand, below is my itemDetail.js

```
(function () {
"use strict";

WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/itemDetail/itemDetail.html", {
    // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
    // populates the page elements with the app's data.


    ready: function (element, options) {
        var item = options && options.item ? Data.resolveItemReference(options.item) : Data.items.getAt(0);
        element.querySelector(".titlearea .pagetitle").textContent = item.group.title;
        element.querySelector("article .item-title").textContent = item.title;
        element.querySelector("article .item-subtitle").textContent = item.subtitle;
        element.querySelector("article .item-image").src = item.backgroundImage;
        element.querySelector("article .item-image").alt = item.subtitle;
        element.querySelector("article .item-content").innerHTML = item.content;
        element.querySelector("article .track1").innerHTML = item.track1;
        WinJS.Utilities.query("#playMP3").listen("click", getStartVideoFuntion("http://www.ikkmusic.com/ikkmusic.com%20mix.mp3"));
    },
});

function getStartVideoFuntion(src) {
    return function () {
        // Set video element's source
        var vid = WinJS.Utilities.query("#playback")[0];
        vid.src = src;
        vid.play();
    };
}})();
```

So I have a file called data.js which has all the sample data in, and I'm getting the info here and displaying it and it works fine, but my problem is with the bottom one (below) where the url is shown, when the button is pressed it plays the url in the html5 player tag, this works, is there a way for me to put the contents of item.track1 where the URL is now, I can't get it to put the contents of the data there.

```
WinJS.Utilities.query("#playMP3").listen("click", getStartVideoFuntion("http://www.ikkmusic.com/ikkmusic.com%20mix.mp3"));
```

Comment: No matter how many times I read that last paragraph I just can't make any sense of what you're trying to do; perhaps you can show us what your markup looks like for .track1

Comment: Really sorry, I will try again, so on this line:

element.querySelector("article .track1").innerHTML = item.track1;

I just printed the contents of item.track1 into the page as text, but on this line:

WinJS.Utilities.query("#playMP3").listen("click", getStartVideoFuntion("PUT CONTENTS OF ITEM.TRACK1 HERE"));

is there a way for me to put the contents of item.track1, which is a web address in that space?

Comment: `WinJS.Utilities.query("#playMP3").listen("click", getStartVideoFuntion(item.track1));` ?

Comment: feel I little silly it was that easy ha, thanks for your help though!

Comment: no problem ;) felt like a bit of a tool for not understanding what you wanted. haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinJS.Utilities.query("#playMP3").listen("click", getStartVideoFuntion(item.track1));